# Window vs Offscreen window

Tags: user-interface, window, gtk, gtk3, glade

In the 3xx versions of [GLADE Interface Designer](https://glade.gnome.org/) there is a toplevel widget called "Offscreen window", which icon has the looking of that: [image]

How it differs from the common window toplevel widget [image] and what is it used for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's used for containing widgets that should not be on screen, yet should be drawn / rendered. According to the [documentation](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkOffscreenWindow.html) the only supported use is screenshots:

> `GtkOffscreenWindow` is strictly intended to be used for obtaining snapshots of widgets that are not part of a normal widget hierarchy.

However, it also sometimes comes in handy for unit tests.

Comment: Any widget the offscreen window contain, doesn't show up. I wanted to find way to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32534734/change-the-windows-opacity-hide-it-without-affecting-its-childs