# Change the window's opacity / hide it without affecting its childs

Tags: c, user-interface, window, gtk, gtk3

I simply have a drawing area, contained in a `GtkWindow` toplevel.

How can I hide the window / make it fully transparent without doing that to its children too (in that case the the drawing area) ?

I am aiming to the case in which everything drawn by the program is just the canvas drawing.